# Angularjs - Cleanest way to add promises to scope, now that Angular deprecated auto unwrapping of promises

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-promise

I really like the clean (and I think easy to follow) way that promises were autounwrapped:

```
$scope.myData = DataService.query({something:"etc"}); // done;
```

And I really don't care for what seems to be the standard way of doing it now, without the automatic unwrapping:

```
DataService.query({something:"etc"}).$promise.then(function (data){
    $scope.myData = data;
});
```

What I'd like to see is something like this:

```
$scope.pulseData = $scope.setPromise(CitsciAnalytics.pulse({
    projId:"yardmap"
}));
```

But I can't see how to make that happen. The closest I got was:

```
$scope.pulseData = $scope.setPromise("pulseData", CitsciAnalytics.pulse({
    projId:"yardmap"
}));
```

Using a function added to the root scope:

```
.run(["$rootScope", "$log", function ($rootScope, $log) {
    //parent method to avoid promise unwrapping boilerplate
    $rootScope.setPromise = function (scopeVar, promise) {
        if (arguments.length === 2 && promise && promise.$promise) {
            var scope = this;
            promise.$promise.then(function (data){
                scope[scopeVar] = data;
            });
        } else {
            $log.error("$rootScope.setPromise has invalid arguments");
        }
    };
}]);
```

but I don't like the unDRY requirement of having to pass the scope variable name as an additional string. Has anyone else tackled this, or see a way to do this more cleanly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all you don't need to use

```
DataService.query({something:"etc"}).$promise.then(function(data){
    $scope.myData = data;
});
```

which clearly refers to a `$resource`, because `$resource` will return an empty array or object and fill it with data as they arrive.

So, with a `$resource` class, you can still use

```
$scope.myData = DetaService.query(...);
```

---

`$resource`'s paradigm is also a good approach to follow in your own "data-fetching" services: Return and empty array and fill it with data as they arrive.

E.g.:

```
.factory('DataService', function ($http) {
    function query(params) {
        var data = [];
        $http.get('/some/url/with/params').then(function (response) {
            response.data.forEach(function (item) {
                data.push(item);
            });
        });
        return data; 
    }

    return {
        query: query
    };
});

.controller('someCtrl', function ($scope, DataService) {
    $scope.data = DataService.query({...});
```

---

If you have to use thrid-party services that return a promise, you can implement your generic function to offer similar functionality:

```
.run(function ($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.promiseToArray = function (promise) {
        var arr = [];
        promise.then(function (data) {
            data.forEach(function (item) {
                arr.push(item);
            });
        });
        return arr;
    };
});

.controller('someCtrl', function ($scope, ThirdPartyService) {
    $scope.data = $scope.promiseToArray(ThirdPartyService.fetchData());
});
```

---

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/2Cn76/)**.

---

<sub>The above samples are just for illustration purposes and not production-ready code.

I a real-world app, you would need to gracefully handle exceptions, rejections etc.</sub>

Comment: ah, thanks for clarifying, also what pixelbits suggested, nice to have the official way to go forward with this-

Comment: so, for people using $resource, this doesn't really affect anything? https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/5dc35b527b3c99f6544b8cb52e93c6510d3ac577

Comment: Exactly ! According to **[the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)**: _"It is important to realize that invoking a `$resource` object method immediately returns an empty reference (object or array depending on `isArray`). Once the data is returned from the server the existing reference is populated with the actual data. This is a useful trick since usually the resource is assigned to a model which is then rendered by the view. [...] This means that in most cases one never has to write a callback function for the action methods."_

Answer (score 0):

We can re-enable unwrapping if we really want to by setting the option to true in a .config() function:

```
.config(function($parseProvider) {
   $parseProvider.unwrapPromises(true) ;
});
```